Verify all codes under one system has one name

Row 4&5 have same value in col C and also have same value in Col D (Correct)
Row 6&7 have same value in Col C but different value in Col D (Incorrect)
So all unique combination in ColA &B who has same value in Col C should have same value on Col D
In other words Col A and B makes an item. all item belong to same category (Col C) should have same price (Col D). It will be incorrect if items belongs to same category but different price
Detail:
I have 4 columns. Column A and B makes a unique key. I need to check all unique values which belong to same value in Column C also have the same value in Column D.
In other words All items (defined by unique combination of Column A and B) which belongs to same category (column C) should have a same price (column D)
I need to write a query in clickhouse SQL to check it.
Checking is not an issue, I can find violation and check if dataframe return >0 records . It's more about how to create that logic of testinf

What have you tried so far? Please provide a [mre]

That's where I am struggling, I need a start , how to think about it in SQL way

Use GROUP BY colA, colB, colC and COUNT(DISTINCT colD)

But then how can I take Col C in the picture

Refresh, I missed that part

This way I cannot check all (colA,colB) belong to one Col C have same Col D

Please show sample input and desired results, I don't understand that part.

If they belong to the same ColD, the COUNT value will be 1.

I added the picture

@Barmar, since (colA, colB) is a unique key for the table per the OP, your suggestion will never return any COUNT greater than 1.

You wrote:

In other words All items (defined by unique combination of Column A and B) which belongs to same category (column C) should have a same price (column D)

That says that the values in column D are a function of column C alone, so what you want to verify is that there is no value of C for which there are multiple values of D:
select C
from my_table
group by C
having count(distinct D) > 1

If that query returns any rows, then your criterion is not satisfied.
But this is a concern only because your data are poorly normalized.  Putting them in third-normal form would remove the possibility of the kind of discrepancy you're looking for.  That would involve moving D to a separate table, with C as its key:

my_table (pk = (A,B))



A
B
C




aa
11
1


aa
12
1


bb
11
2


bb
12
2



my_other_table (pk = (C))



C
D




1
123


2
456




